# Need to Rearrange for P

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$E=2.5\cdot P\cdot V\cdot \left(1-\left(\frac xP\right)^{.286}\right)$$

Missed a variable last time. Still can not isolate for P. Last time the formula was edited incorrectly.

Comment: you cannot isolate $P$ but you can find $P$ only numerically

Comment: There is no way to rearrange that formula to write as a function of P?

Comment: The formula is already a function of $P$.  What are you attempting to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

First, notice that we can partially isolate $P$
$$
\frac{E}{2.5V}=P\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{P}\right)^{0.286}\right)
$$
Then we can work out the right side a bit
$$
P\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{P}\right)^{0.286}\right)=P\left(1-\frac{x^{0.286}}{P^{0.286}}\right)=P-P^{0.714}x^{0.286}
$$
then we have 'an equation in $P$'
$$
P-x^{0.286}P^{0.714}-\frac{E}{2.5V}=0
$$
Now we have an equation which is 'set up' for Numerical Analysis using a variety of different methods. However, in terms of solving for $P$, that is about as good as it gets. One should not be able to isolate just $P$ here, at least not 'trivially'. In general, one can't. Often, putting these equations into a program like Mathematica or [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) gives one a fairly good indication if such things are solvable for a particular variable.

Comment: I think your second equation has a mixed-up exponent... and this leads to mistakes in the third and fourth equations...

Comment: @abiessu How so? Are you keeping in mind what we really have after distribution is $P\cdot P^{-0.286}=P^{-0.714}$?

Comment: Yes, but we really have $P\cdot P^{-.286}=P^{.714}$...

Comment: @abiessu Oh yes! What a trivial error to make! Thank you for catching it!

Comment: Basically I am trying to rearrange this formula for P to calculate and write out a table for work. I can calculate the values for E, V and X so I just need the equation in a format where I can solve for the value of P. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @thomas We know what you are looking for. However, not every equation has a 'formula'. Sometimes things can only be approximated once you know the other variables. If you can calculate the other variables, plug them all in then solve the single variable equation for $P$. As the equation currently stands, it cannot be solved.

Comment: @thomas Not a problem. It surprises most people when they learn that not everything can be solved. This was a long standing problem in Mathematics when mathematicians wondered if there was a 'quadratic formula' that would solve all polynomials. However, as Abel and Galois showed, nearly all polynomials *can't* have a formula and one can only hope to find their zeros using numerical analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing multiplication yields

$$E=2.5\cdot P\cdot V\cdot \left(1-\left(\frac xP\right)^{.286}\right)=2.5\cdot P\cdot V-2.5\cdot P^{1-.286}\cdot V\cdot x^{.286}$$

or

$$E=2.5\cdot V\cdot\left(P-P^{.714}x^{.286}\right)=2.5\cdot V\cdot P^{.714}\left(P^{.286}-x^{.286}\right)$$

"Isolating $P$" is not guaranteed to give a useful result here; in particular, the equation above is a $500$-degree polynomial (in exponents of measure $.002$) on the right-hand-side.  This polynomial is not generally soluble in terms of $P$.